# multiple relationships between two entities_mscrm 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created four 1:N relationships between Contact and a custom entity.In the form for the custom entity the Look ups come with the proper display names which I had set while creating the relationships.However, in the contact form,in the left navigation pane,there are four identical links with the name of the custom entity.Can anyone help? how to provide a unique name to the left navigation links.In the custom enity form the look-ups come with the proper display names provided.However, in the form for contact the left navigation links are all of the same name i.e that of the custom entity.Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here described how to [Change Form Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328217.aspx) To have a full control over navigation pane on entity form, you are able to edit Form XML. To do this you should export the entity customizations, edit form XML and import the customizations back in CRM.

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple N:N Relationships and give each related Contact a custom label. The new name will show up as the custom label. It will also use the custom label as part of the relationship name.